# General Evaluation of Credentials

Tags: graduate-admissions

I just received news that I've been recommended for admission to a Ph.D. program(!!!) and that I will receive an official offer letter once the graduate office has conducted an evaluation of my credentials. Since they haven't asked me to take any steps, I assume that they are just checking that my transcripts are accurate, etc.? I am a U.S. citizen who only went to college in the States. When I look up this topic, I only find information on international students. They've asked me to confirm in early April, so I assume that their grad office already has all they need to evaluate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations. What's done in the gap between a university sending an offer and a contract/appointment letter isn't particularly uniform in the US. You are right that the Department or University will be very explicit in correspondence with you about what they need you to do if you'd like to accept their offer. If they need additional information from you for administrative purposes they're going to follow up with you.

Comment: thank you for your response! I will follow up to ask if any steps are needed from me.